# How to insert each field of an object in different rows using jdbcTemplate?

Tags: spring

I have a pojo class ,which contains some fields like below and each field contains some value.
So, how can i insert each field in different rows as Key,Value pair

```
private String hostName;
private String sharedAccessKey;
private String azureMongoDbUri;
private String sharedAccessKeyName;
private String azureDatabase;
private String azureCollection;

ColumnName = property_key | property_value
records    = hostName     | pojo.getHostName();
             sharedAccessKey| pojo.getSharedAccessKey();
```

and so on.

Comment: please elaborate more, what do you mean by insert each field in different rows ?

Answer (score -2):

This is an example of how to insert a record to the database using the JdbcTemplate class provided by the Spring Framework. The JdbcTemplate class is the central class in the JDBC core package. It simplifies the use of JDBC and helps to avoid common errors. It executes core JDBC workflow, leaving application code to provide SQL and extract results. This class executes SQL queries or updates, initiating iteration over ResultSets and catching JDBC exceptions. Inserting a record to the database with JdbcTemplate class implies that you should:

Use the DataSource class, a utility class that provides connection to the database. It is part of the JDBC specification and allows a container or a framework to hide connection pooling and transaction management issues from the application code. We implement it using the org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource. Set the credentials needed to the datasource, using the inherited methods setPassword(String password), setUrl(String url) and setUsername(String username) API methods of AbstractDriverBasedDataSource class, as also the setDriverClassName(String driverClassName) API method of DriverManagerDataSource. Create a new Datasource object having the above configuration. Here in getDatasource() method we create a new Datasource and configure it.
Create a new JdbcTemplate object, with the given datasource to obtain connections from.
Use the update(String sql, Object args, int[] argTypes) API method of JdbcTemplate, to issue the SQL insert operation via a prepared statement, binding the given arguments. The given parameters are the String containing the sql query, the arguments to bind the query, and the types of the arguments. It returns the number of rows processed by the executed query.
Let’s take a look at the code snippet that follows:

```
package com.javacodegeeks.snippets.enterprise;

import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

public class InsertRecordInDatabaseWithJdbcTemplate {

    private static final String driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/companydb";
    private static final String dbUsername = "jcg";
    private static final String dbPassword = "jcg";

    private static final String insertSql =

  "INSERT INTO employee (" +

  " name, " +

  " surname, " +

  " title, " +

  " created) " +

  "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

    private static DataSource dataSource;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        dataSource = getDataSource();

        saveRecord("John", "Black", "Software developer", new Date());
        saveRecord("Tom", "Green", "Project Manager", new Date());

    }

    public static void saveRecord(String name, String surname, String title, Date created) {

        JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

        // define query arguments
        Object[] params = new Object[] { name, surname, title, new Date() };

        // define SQL types of the arguments
        int[] types = new int[] { Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR, Types.TIMESTAMP };

        // execute insert query to insert the data
        // return number of row / rows processed by the executed query
        int row = template.update(insertSql, params, types);
        System.out.println(row + " row inserted.");

    }

    public static DriverManagerDataSource getDataSource() {

  DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

  dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);

  dataSource.setUrl(url);

  dataSource.setUsername(dbUsername);

  dataSource.setPassword(dbPassword);

  return dataSource;
    }

}
```